# trying to draw over sprite or change picture pyglet

Tags: python, sprite, pyglet

I am trying to learn pyglet and practice some python coding with a questionnaire thing, but I am unable to find a way to make the background picture be removed or drawn on top of or something for 10 seconds. I am new and am lacking in a lot of the knowledge I would need, thank you for helping!

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import Window
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet import image
import time

card1 = False
cat_image = pyglet.image.load("cat.png")
dog_image = pyglet.image.load("dog.png")
image = pyglet.image.load("backg.png")
background_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(image)
cat = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(cat_image)
dog = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(dog_image)
window = pyglet.window.Window(638, 404, "Life")
mouse_pos_x = 0
mouse_pos_y = 0
catmeme = pyglet.image.load("catmeme.png")
sprite_catmeme = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(catmeme)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    background_sprite.draw()
    card_draw1(63, 192, 385, 192)
def card1():
    while time.time() < (time.time() + 10):
        window.clear()
        sprite_catmeme.draw()
@window.event
def card_draw1(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    cat.set_position(x1, y1)
    dog.set_position(x2, y2)
    cat.draw()
    dog.draw()
def card_draw2():
    pass
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if x > cat.x and x < (cat.x + cat.width):
        if y > cat.y and y < (cat.y + cat.height):
            card1()
game = True
while game:
    on_draw()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: also, if you have any tips to help my code improve that would be appreciated!!.

Comment: To my below answer, I usually toss this on people as well: http://hvornum.se/pyglet/ - It's been a work in progress for ages and I can never really get the time to tidy it up. Mostly just a rant but there's some pieces in there that is great to use and it explains a few things. One day I might actually get around to make it look good and more educational. But for now, it's mostly a rant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few flaws in the order and in which you do things.
I will try my best to describe them and give you a piece of code that might work better for what your need is.

I also think your description of the problem is a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is quite common when asking for help on complex matters where you think you're close to a solution, so you're asking for help on the solution you've come up with and not the problem.

I'm assuming you want to show a "Splash screen" for 10 seconds, which happens to be your background? And then present the `cat.png` and `dog.png` ontop of it, correct?

If that's the case, here's where you probably need to change things in order for it to work:

**The `draw()` function**

It doesn't really update the screen much, it simply adds things to the graphical memory. What updates the screen is you or something telling the graphics library that you're done adding things to the screen and it's time to update everything you've `.draw()`'n. So the last thing you need in the loop would be `window.flip()` in order for the things you've drawn to actually show.

Your things might show if you try to wiggle the window around, it should trigger a re-draw of the scene because of how the internal mechanics of pyglet work..

If you don't call `.flip()` - odds are probable that the `redraw()` call will never occur - which again, is a internal mechanism of Pyglet/GL that tells the graphics card that something has been updated, we're done updating and it's time to redraw the scene.

**a scene**

This is the word most commonly used for what the user is seeing.
I'll probably throw this around a lot in my text, so it's good to know that this is what the user is seeing, not what you've `.draw()`'n or what's been deleted, it's the last current rendering of the graphics card to the monitor.

But because of how graphical buffers work we've might have removed or added content to the memory without actually drawing it yet. Keep this in mind.

**The `pyglet.app.run()` call**

This is a never ending loop in itself, so having that in a `while game:` loop doesn't really make sense because `.run()` will "hang" your entire application, any code you want to execute needs to be in `def on_draw` or an `event` that is generated from within the graphical code itself.

To better understand this, have a look at my code, i've pasted it around a couple of times here on SO over the years and it's a basic model of two custom classes that inherits the behavior of Pyglet but lets you design your own classes to behave slightly differently.

And most of the functionality is under `on_???` functions, which is almost always a function used to catch [Events](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/events.html). Pyglet has a lot of these built in, and we're going to override them with our own (but the names must be the same)

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

key = pyglet.window.key

class CustomSprite(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, texture_file, x=0, y=0):
        ## Must load the texture as a image resource before initializing class:Sprite()
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load(texture_file)

        super(CustomSprite, self).__init__(self.texture)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _draw(self):
        self.draw()

class MainScreen(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(800, 600, fullscreen = False)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.bg = CustomSprite('bg.jpg')
        self.sprites = {}
        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0
        elif symbol == key.C:
            print('Rendering cat')
            self.sprites['cat'] = CustomSprite('cat.png', x=10, y=10)
        elif symbol == key.D:
            self.sprites['dog'] = CustomSprite('dog.png', x=100, y=100)

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        self.bg.draw()

        for sprite_name, sprite_obj in self.sprites.items():
            sprite_obj._draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = MainScreen()
x.run()
```

Now, this code is kept simple on purpose, the full code I usually paste on SO can be found at [Torxed/PygletGui](https://github.com/Torxed/PygletGui), the [gui.py](https://github.com/Torxed/PygletGui/blob/master/gui.py) is where most of this comes from and it's the main loop.

What I do here is simply replace the [Decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) by using "actual" functions inside a class. The class itself inherits the functions from a traditional `pyglet.window.Window`, and as soon as you name the functions the same as the inherited onces, you replace the core functionality of `Window()` with whatever you decide.. In this case, i mimic the same functions but add a few of my own.

### on_key_press

One such example is `on_key_press()`, which normally just contain a `pass` call and does nothing, here, we check if `key.C` is pressed, and if so - we add a item to `self.sprites`.. `self.sprites` just so happen to be in our `render()` loop, anything in there will be rendered ontop of a background.

Here's the pictures I used:

(named `bg.jpg`, `cat.png`, `dog.png` - **note the different file endings**)

[image: bg.jpg]
[image: cat.png]
[image: dog.png]

### class:CustomSprite

`CustomSprite` is a very simple class designed to make your life easier at this point, nothing else. It's very limited in functionality but the little it do is awesome.

It's soul purpose is to take a file name, load it as an image and you can treat the object like a traditional `pyglet.sprite.Sprite`, meaning you can move it around and manipulate it in many ways.

It saves a few lines of code having to load all the images you need and as you can see in [gui_classes_generic.py](https://github.com/Torxed/PygletGui/blob/master/gui_classes_generic.py) you can add a heap of functions that's "invisible" and normally not readily availbale to a normal sprite class.

I use this a bunch! But the code gets complicated real fast so I kept this post simple on purpose.

### the flip function

Even in my class, I still need to use `flip()` in order to update the contents of the screen. This is because `.clear()` clears the window as you would expect, that also triggers a redraw of the scene.

`bg.draw()` might in some cases trigger a redraw if the data is big enough or if something else happens, for instance you move the window.

but calling `.flip()` will tell the GL backend to force a redraw.

### Further optimizations

There's a thing called **batched rendering**, basically the graphic card is designed to take enormous ammounts of data and render it in one go, so calling `.draw()` on several items will only clog the CPU before the GPU even gets a chance to shine. Read more about [Batched rendering and graphics](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/pyglet.graphics.html)! It will save you a lot of frame rates.

Another thing is to keep as little functionality as possible in the `render()` loop and use the event triggers as your main source of coding style.
Pyglet does a good job of being fast, especially if you only do things on event driven tasks.

Try to avoid timers, but if you really do need to use time for things, such as removing `cat.png` after a certain ammount of time, use the [clock/time event](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/time.html) to call a function that removes the cat. Do not try to use your own `t = time()` style of code unless you know where you're putting it and why. There's a good timer, I rarely use it.. But you should if you're starting off.

This has been one hell of a wall of text, I hope it educated you some what in the life of graphics and stuff. Keep going, it's a hurdle to get into this kind of stuff but it's quite rewarding once you've mastered it (I still haven't) :)

Comment: thank you so much I thought no one would  help, you are amazing

Comment: i am just learning but you have encouraged me to keep going, I want you to know that this has been a huge help

Comment: @S0me0ne It's my absolute pleasure! It's just fun to hear someone getting inspired to try more, programming isn't about success in the beginning really.. It's about struggling and finding aways around the obstacles without giving up :) It's hard work, it will almost always be - but the end result is almost almost worth it :) Best of luck to you!