# Sprite in Pyglet not doing what I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I am trying to have a circle that, when clicked, moves somewhere else on the screen. However, when I click the circle, nothing happens.

```
#IMPORT STUFF
import pyglet as pg
from random import randint

mouse = pg.window.mouse

#VARS
window = pg.window.Window(width = 640, height = 480)
score = 0
circleImg = pg.image.load("circle.png")
circle = pg.sprite.Sprite(circleImg, randint(1, window.width), randint(1, window.height))
text = pg.text.Label("Click red!", font_name = "Times New Roman", font_size = 18, x = 260, y = 10)


#DETECT MOUSE PRESS ON CIRCLE
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if x == circle.x and y == circle.y:
        circle.x = randint(1, window.width)
        circle.y = randint(1, window.height)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    text.draw()
    circle.draw()

pg.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from random import randint

glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

class Circle(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, radiance=5, x=0, y=0):
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load('circle.png')
        super(Circle, self).__init__(self.texture)

    def click(self, x, y):
        if x >= self.x and y >= self.y:
            if x <= self.x + self.texture.width and y <= self.y + self.texture.height:
                return self

mouse = pyglet.window.mouse

#VARS
window = pyglet.window.Window(width = 640, height = 480)
score = 0
#circleImg = pyglet.image.load("circle.png")
#circle = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(circleImg, randint(1, window.width), randint(1, window.height))
circle = Circle(x=50, y=50)
text = pyglet.text.Label("Click red!", font_name = "Times New Roman", font_size = 18, x = 260, y = 10)


#DETECT MOUSE PRESS ON CIRCLE
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if circle.click(x, y):
        print('Clicked in circle')
        circle.x = randint(0, window.width - 10)
        circle.y = randint(0, window.height - 10)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    text.draw()
    circle.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

A short description of what this does is it creates a custom class called `Circle` that inherits the `Sprite` class. It loads the `circle.png` as a texture with a alpha channel that gets blended by the GL library.

We add a custom function called `click` that checks if the lowest `x,y` coordinates are higher than the circles lowest `x,y`, then we check if the cursor is below `x+width` and same for `y` of the image region.

If that's the case, we return the circle sprite class as a `True` value in case we want to use the sprite.

### Future enhancements:

You should draw the circle using [gl functions](https://gist.github.com/davepape/6622881), hence why I've defined `radiance` in the class definitions. However **radiance here is never used, it's a placeholder for the future**.
This is so you can use math to defined if you actually clicked within the circle, but this is beyond my scope of quick answers.. I would have to do a lot of debugging myself in order to get the math to add up (it's not my strong side).

What makes it work now is that we use the image width, height, x and y data to crudely check if we're within the image, aka "the circle".

---

- [trying to draw over sprite or change picture pyglet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963164/trying-to-draw-over-sprite-or-change-picture-pyglet/40975026#40975026)

As a bonus, I'll add this answer to the list of enhancements because it contains some stuff that might be useful. One would be to replace 90% of your code with a custom `pyglet.window.Window` class to replace global variables and decorators and stuff.

And it would look something like this:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from random import randint

glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

key = pyglet.window.key

class Circle(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, radiance=5, x=0, y=0):
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load('circle.png')
        super(Circle, self).__init__(self.texture)

    def click(self, x, y):
        if x >= self.x and y >= self.y:
            if x <= self.x + self.texture.width and y <= self.y + self.texture.height:
                return self

class MainScreen(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(800, 600, fullscreen = False)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.bg = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('background.jpg'))
        self.sprites = {}
        self.sprites['circle'] = Circle(x=50, y=50)
        self.sprites['label'] = pyglet.text.Label("Click red!", font_name = "Times New Roman", font_size = 18, x = 260, y = 10)
        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if self.sprites['circle'].click(x, y):
            print('Clicked in circle')
            self.sprites['circle'].x = randint(0, self.width - 10)
            self.sprites['circle'].y = randint(0, self.height - 10)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        self.bg.draw()

        for sprite_name, sprite_obj in self.sprites.items():
            sprite_obj.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = MainScreen()
x.run()
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pyglet, but I'm guessing the problem is that you're checking whether `x == circle.x` etc, which means it only moves when you click the single pixel at the exact centre of the circle. Try some kind of maximum distance from the centre (e.g. a hypotenuse `math.sqrt( (x-circle.x)**2 + (y-circle.y)**2) < circle.radius`

Comment: I get the idea, but class `sprite` has no attribute `radius`. I don't know how to implement your idea in pyglet, but thanks anyway!